# asp.net mvc form authenticate lose cookie session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication, model-view-controller

asp.net mvc project when publish, it always lose session after 15-20 minutes.

my global.asax

```
enter code  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);


    }

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
            {
                var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);
            }
        }
    }
```

Login Method :

```
   //clear any other tickets that are already in the response
                    Response.Cookies.Clear();

                    //set the new expiry date - to thirty days from now
                    DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

                    //create a new forms auth ticket
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, login.EmailID, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, true, "Kullanici Bilgisi");


                    //encrypt the ticket
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);


                    //create a new authentication cookie - and set its expiration date
                    HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                    authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                    authenticationCookie.HttpOnly = true;

                    //add the cookie to the response.
                    Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);
```

Please help me. Im control on google developer tools. I see timeout 2018 but session is always losing redirect to login page.

Web Config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/user/login" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>

</authentication>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Hi everybody. I solved my problem. iis is always resetting so  am recording session informations on file.

Comment: Could you show me how you did it?

Comment: @RodrigoPrieto I have a database table as session. İf user login, ı recorded and in each request ı am controlling session state. İn addition , in every login, ı generate complex string for session. I record this string as cookie and save in session table. in each request, ı compare them.